# Handle pagination with recyclerview gridlayout manager dynamically in android

Tags: android, api, android-recyclerview, pagination, gridlayoutmanager

I am implementing pagination to show data from API by using the recyclerview gridlayout manager. I have tried multiple ways to implement it, finally found a solution but still, it is not working properly. I show data in the list from API, but whenever my data shows in recyclerview from API then it's on scrolllistener automatically works which it should only when I scroll the list.
I am adding a snippet of my code below.

```
    private lateinit var scrollListener: RecyclerviewLoadMore
        private lateinit var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    
        //int
        private var pageNum = 1
        private var limit = 0

motivationAdapter = MotivationsAdapter(requireActivity(), getVideoList, object : RecyclerViewClickHandler {
            override fun onItemClicked(position: Int, type: Int, view: View) {

        })

    rvMotivation?.adapter = motivationAdapter
    rvMotivation?.addItemDecoration(SpacesItemDecoration(2, 30, false))
    mLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(), 2)
    rvMotivation?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    (mLayoutManager as GridLayoutManager).spanSizeLookup =
        object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return when (motivationAdapter?.getItemViewType(position)) {
                    RecyclerScrollEnums.VIEW_TYPE_ITEM.viewType -> 1
                    RecyclerScrollEnums.VIEW_TYPE_LOADING.viewType -> 2 //number of columns of the grid
                    else -> -1
                }
            }
        }
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        //scroll listener
        scrollListener = RecyclerviewLoadMore(mLayoutManager as GridLayoutManager)
        scrollListener.setOnLoadMoreListener(object :
            OnLoadMoreListener {
            override fun onLoadMore() {
                //Get the number of the current Items of the main Arraylist
                val start = motivationAdapter?.itemCount
                scrollListener.isLoading = false
                if(scrollListener.lastVisibleItem==limit){
                    motivationAdapter?.addLoadingView()
                    getVideoAPi()
                }

            }
        })
        rvMotivation?.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
    }, 1000)
```

I notify data when getting data from the API success.

```
if (response.success == SOCKET_TRUE) {
                    pageNum += 1
                   
                    if (limit>0) {
                        motivationAdapter?.removeLoadingView()
                    }
                    limit += response?.data?.size!!
                    updateAdapterCategory(response.data)

                } 
 fun updateAdapterCategory(getMotivatedList: ArrayList<DataItem?>?) {
    getVideoList?.addAll(getMotivatedList!!)
    motivationAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

This recyclerview scroll listener class which I found on the internet.

```
class RecyclerviewLoadMore : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    private var visibleThreshold = 5
    private lateinit var mOnLoadMoreListener: OnLoadMoreListener
    internal var isLoading: Boolean = false
    internal var lastVisibleItem: Int = 0
    internal var totalItemCount: Int = 0
    private var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    //linear layout manager
    constructor(layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager
    }
    //grid layout manager
    constructor(layoutManager: GridLayoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager
        visibleThreshold *= layoutManager.spanCount
    }
    //staggered layout manager
    constructor(layoutManager: StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager
        visibleThreshold *= layoutManager.spanCount
    }

    //interface to load more data for pagination
    fun setOnLoadMoreListener(mOnLoadMoreListener: OnLoadMoreListener) {
        this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener
    }


    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.itemCount

        if (mLayoutManager is StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            val lastVisibleItemPositions =
                (mLayoutManager as StaggeredGridLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null)
            // get maximum element within the list
            lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions)
        } else if (mLayoutManager is GridLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItem = (mLayoutManager as GridLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()

        } else if (mLayoutManager is LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItem = (mLayoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        }

        if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold) {
            mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore()
            isLoading = true
        }
    }

    private fun getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions: IntArray): Int {
        var maxSize = 0
        for (i in lastVisibleItemPositions.indices) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i]
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i]
            }
        }
        return maxSize
    }
}
```